# Asking if an infinite series will converge or diverge

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

I have two questions regarding the convergence of infinite series. One, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges to L, where L is defined, does $a_n < L$ for each n?

Two, if $a_n$ is defined for each n, and $\sum_{n=j}^{\infty}a_n$ converges for some integer j, then does $\sum_{n=j}^{\infty}a_n$ converge for all j?

My response: for one, this is a no for me, since you can make $a_n=0$, which will promptly converge to 0, but $0 \not < 0$. For two, I think this is based right off of one of the properties of series, where if a portion of the series converges, then the entire series converges, right? Correct me if I'm wrong (:

Comment: Consider the series $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}+\ldots$ This series converges to $2/3$, but it is not true that each term is smaller than $2/3$.

Comment: @Joe that is a good point. What about n. two?

Comment: I *think* your statement is correct, although I would prefer using a different letter: e.g. I would say if $\sum_{n=i}^{\infty}a_n$ converges for some integer $i$, then it must be true that $\sum_{n=j}^{\infty}a_n$ converges for another integer $j$. But please don't take my word for it: I might be mistaken. Hopefully someone else more qualified than me can address that my part of your question.

Comment: @Joe good to hear. I will wait until someone gives an answer. Thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are more or less correct for both questions, but we can expand on this a little bit.

1. Note that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=0$. Now, consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{n^{2}}=-\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}=L$. It follows that $a_{n}>L$ for sufficiently large $n$ since $L$ is negative and $a_{n}$ must eventually be getting very close to zero.
2. Your intuition is essentially right here. For example, if $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{j}$ converges and you ignore finitely-many terms of the series, then the remaining sum still converges.